# Azure data extract automated email to users

Tags: excel, automation, outlook, azure-data-factory

I am trying to see if it is possible to take a database in azure data factory and filter a field by all options and auto extract the data to excel and email different filtered database outputs to different users.

If this solution possible in ADF or can this be done somewhere else?

Simplified example: 100k records of data, 30 fields. 1 field for car color. Data includes Red, Green, and Blue. Id like to filter and export all data associated with each of the 3 filters (3 extracts) and send each file as an excel export and email to a unique individual for each color (Red goes to Bob, Green goes to Ryan, Blue goes to Nick) in an automated/scheduled refresh fashion.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There's no native "send an email" task in ADF. MS will point you in the direction of Azure functions (as per the suggestion below). Then you need to consider: why not just write all of it in Azure functions. Are you interested in historically knowing who you sent an email to and when?

Answer (score 0):

I think this a doable and this is what i think .

1. Use a lookup activity something like

> SELECT DISTINCT color FROM TABLE .

2.Use a for each loop and now add a copy activity and in the Source use a query like
@Concat( 'SELECT A,B,C from TABLE where color= ' ,Lookup.activity.color ) ( this is not the correct synatax  annd in the sync point to the blob location  .

3. Add the Azure function activity and use that to send the email . In the email you can add the email again by filtering the  metatadat table in the SQL on the color .

The email should have the link to the blob location .